# Export HTML table to PDF, WORD, PNG using TableExport.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, html2pdf

I am trying to export a Table via PDF using the js provided by [Ngiriraj Table Export Demo.](http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php)
The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/base64.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<button id="export" style="height: auto; width: auto;" onClick="$('#tableID').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">Click Here for PDF!</button>


<table id="tableID">
<tr>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>BDE</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I click on the button, nothing happens. Console shows a error **UNCAUGHT TYPE ERROR** whenever the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include any scripts reliant on jQuery after the jQuery.  I'd say best practice is to put jQuery first.  Let me know if this works:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/tableExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/base64.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot. But how can i download the PDF file?

Comment: Hmm... For that I'm not quite sure.  I don't know that javascript library at all.  At least in Chrome, you'll have a little "save" button in the bottom right.  I'm not sure about the other browsers, thought.  Perhaps under File > Save?

Comment: It downloads as an Unknown file type, even though file type is provided. Any fix for that?

Comment: How to export multiple html tables into multiple sheets in same excel using tableexport.js?